# quirks of using Angular Shadow DOM CSS Selector

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular, just a question on applying Shadow DOM CSS Selector. Below is some pseudo code:

```
//root template.html
<div id="first">
   <div id="second">
       <paProductForm ..."></paProductForm>
   <div>
</div>
```

where `paProductForm` is the selector of my custom component as:

```
@Component({
    selector: "paProductForm",
    templateUrl: "productForm.component.html",
    styles: ["/deep/ div { border: 2px black solid; font-style:italic }"]
})
export class ProductFormComponent {
   ...
}
```

I was told that `/deep` is used by a parent component to define styles
that affect the elements in child component templates, so that means in my case, the style should only apply to `<div>` inside productForm.component.html and also child components if it has.
But it actually setup a global style element in the head of the client side of html as
[image]
which means that the style will also apply on "div" elements with id of "first" and "second", which is not what I want and not the goal of `/deep` as it claims to be?

Comment: /deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep - deprecated

Answer (score 0):

According To [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles):

> Applying the ::ng-deep pseudo-class to any CSS rule completely disables view-encapsulation for that rule. **Any style with ::ng-deep applied becomes a global style**. In order to scope the specified style to the current component and all its descendants, be sure to include the :host selector before ::ng-deep. If the ::ng-deep combinator is used without the :host pseudo-class selector, the style can bleed into other components.

`/deep` and `::ng-deep` **are the same**, except `::ng-deep` is supported by SASS, (both of which are marked deprecated and should be avoided)

Answer (score 0):

From: Adam Freeman Book “Pro Angular 9.” :

Using the **shadow DOM** means that there are boundaries that regular **CSS** selectors do not operate across. To help address this, there are a number of special CSS selectors that are useful when using styles that rely on the shadow DOM (even when it is being emulated), as described below:

**:host**
This selector is used to match the component’s host element.

**:host-context(classSelector)**
This selector is used to match the ancestors of the host element that are members of a specific class.

**/deep/ or >>>**
This selector is used by a parent component to define styles that affect the elements in child component templates. This selector should be used only when the **@Component decorator’s** encapsulation property is set to emulated.